# wait for FB.logout() in onclick event

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I need to call `FB.logout()` and log out of the application at once. To logout from app it's needed to hit `DELETE /signout` which happens after clicking `#sign_out_btn`. I binded onclick event to the button to call `FB.logout()` before it happens.

My first attempt:

```
$('#sign_out_btn').click(function(e) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      FB.logout(function(response){
        return true;
      });
    } else {
      return true;
  });
});
```

did not work, because `FB.logout()` is called asynchronously and app proceeds to execute `DELETE /signout` call and redirects, so the `FB.logout()` call is never made.

I came up with a workaround in which I prevent from making the original call to server on button click and make `DELETE` request using `ajax` in `logout` callback and redirect page manually afterwards:

```
$('#sign_out_btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/signout',
          type: 'DELETE',
          success: function(result) {
            return window.location = '/';
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

It works, but it doesn't really seem to be a clever solution. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a legit solution imho. To avoid the "callback hell", you could also use Promises. Here are some useful resources about that:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://www.promisejs.org/

Btw, i would use `FB.getLoginStatus` on page load only, and store the information if the user is logged in. You would save an API call in the logout procedure that way.